# MobileFirst nonBuild refresh - in 6.3?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

In answer to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417956/ionic-ibm-mobilefirst)

I confidently said:

> The need to rebuild in order to see changes in your Web components
>   (CSS, JavaScript, HTML) did used to be an annoyance in early versions
>   of what was then Worklight and is now MobileFirst. I forget when the
>   need for a rebuild was removed but certainly in Worklight 6.2 and
>   beyond you now simply need to refresh in your browser.
>
> My personal practice is always to have Mobile Web environment in my
>   project and then choose that from the Console. This loads the
>   application in the browser-based Mobile Simulator that you can tailor
>   to fit your target form-factor. This has a "Go/Refresh" button that
>   immediately reflects your edits.

However I'm now working in 6.3.0.00-20150106-1717 and ... it seems to be necessary to rebuild and redeploy to see any changes to my HTML, CSS and JavaScript. In 6.2 things work as expected.

I am about to try a later version of Studio, thought it was worth asking that the referenced question had identified a defect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that updating (Help->Check for Updates) to 6.3.0.00-20150214-1702 fixes the issue, I can now edit, save, go/refresh and see my changes without needing a rebuild or redeploy.

Comment: Indeed, we had a bug there. Fixed.